# Flexbox: flex-shrink not working in IE11 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a block on my page where 2 images should stand next to each other. Depending on there width, they should scale accordantly.

Thank god we have Flexbox for that!
Now this demo works in Chrome, Safari, FF and IE Edge:

http://codepen.io/IbeVanmeenen/pen/PqgOJM

```
.el {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;

  margin: 4rem 0;
}

.el__wrp {
  display: block;

  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;

  justify-content: space-around;

  min-width: 0px;
}
```

But the problem is that in IE11 and 10, the flex shrink seems to be ignored, resulting in the first image been shown full width and the second one disappearing...

Anyone have a clue how to fix this..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, fixed this!

I updated the pen.
I tested the original code, but replaced the images with text, and it worked! So the problem was the images.

Original code for the images was:

```
.el__wrp img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;

  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: auto;
}
```

And I changed it to:

```
.el__wrp img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;

  width: 100%;
}
```

It all works now!

Answer (score 0):

The IE 10 and 11 has bug when using min-height. It's known issues and you can find the issue for example here https://caniuse.com/#search=flex